# Use of getters in ResultSets

Tags: java, mysql, resultset

I am trying to write java code to access a table 'customer' with columns 'customer_id', 'email', 'deliverable', and 'create_date'

I have

```
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, connectionUser, connectionPassword);
        Statement constat = conn.createStatement();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE customer_id LIKE " + customerId;
        ResultSet rtn = constat.executeQuery(query);
        Customer cust = new Customer(rtn.getInt("customer_id"), rtn.getString("email"),  rtn.getInt("deliverable"), rtn.getString("create_date"));
        conn.close();
        return cust;
```

I am receiving the error:

java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set

As far as I can tell, my error is in the line where I am creating a new Customer object, but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Can anyone offer me some help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must always go to the next row by calling `resultSet.next()` (and checking it returns true), before accessing the data of the row:

```
Customer cust = null;
if (rtn.next()) {
    cust = new Customer(rtn.getInt("customer_id"), 
                        rtn.getString("email"), 
                        rtn.getInt("deliverable"), 
                        rtn.getString("create_date"));
}
```

Note that you should also

- use prepared statements instead of String concatenation to avoid SQL injection attacks, and have more robust code
- close the connections, statements and resultsets in a finally block, or use the try-with-resources construct if using Java 7

Read the [JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/)

Answer (score 0):

You should call [`ResultSet.first()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/sql/ResultSet.html) to move the result to the first position. The result set is a programming convention not to retrieve the whole result of the query and keep in memory. As such, its interface is quite low level and you must explicit select the row via methods like `first()`, `last()` or `next()` (each returns `true` to check if the requested row index is in the set)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
rtn.next();
```

before you use the result set.

Usually this is done as

```
while (rtn.next()) {
  <do something with the row>
}
```